# Problems with setting up a non-exit relay

Tags: relays, ssl

I would like to contribute to the Tor Project and set up a non-exit relay. But there are some problems:

1. Even if self-testing indicates my `ORPort` and `DirPort` are reachable from the outside, it doesn't receive anything at all. Well, it receives ~ 10KBs per minute, or only a few MBs per day!
2. Average speed is ~ 3 KB/s, even if I set average bandwidth rate ~ 5 MB/s!
3. My relay isn't displayed in the Tor Network Map.

All these old problems are here since April, and as I didn't found a solution, I stopped running the relay. But a few days ago I decided to try again, and here's new problem:

- The directory server rejects my relay descriptor with message:

> [Warning] http status 400 ("Fingerprint is marked rejected") response from dirserver 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx'.

As Google says, that's because of old version of OpenSSL, but the problem is that I have never installed OpenSSL.

So, I hope you know how to help me. I've been searching for the solution over the Internet and asked questions  on some forums, but nobody answered.

Answer (score 2):

This is a clip from the emailed response I got back in May 2014 when I had the same problem.

I'm on a windows machine and I didn't see how the answer gets used to help me run a relay again even though I've run one many times before with no problem. But this MAY help you, and I'll hope for enough info in time to help me fix this W7 machine to run the Vidalia relay bundle again. I wonder how many other potential windows relay folks are similarly waiting for a solution.

"As it says, your relay is being rejected. This is because your relay is
still vulnerable to the “Heartbleed” vulnerability or your key is considered
as possibly compromised. For more details please see:

https://blog.torproject.org/blog/openssl-bug-cve-2014-0160

And articles in past Tor Weekly News editions:

https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-weekly-news-%E2%80%94-april-9th-2014"

It won't let me post more than 2 links, but the 3rd was the same as that 2nd one but change the date to this: april-16th-2014